# Find the sum of all real numbers x that satisfy

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Find the sum of all real numbers x that satisfy

$(\sqrt{x^2-2020x+2021})+\sqrt{x^2-2020x+2019})^{\frac{3x}{2}}+(\sqrt{x^2-2020x+2021})-\sqrt{x^2-2020x+2019})^{\frac{3x}{2}}=2^{1+\frac{3x}{4}}$

My Answer :

Square the two sides

$(\sqrt{x^2-2020x+2021})+\sqrt{x^2-2020x+2019})^{3x}+(\sqrt{x^2-2020x+2021})-\sqrt{x^2-2020x+2019})^{3x}=2^{1+\frac{3x}{2}}$

Let $a=(\sqrt{x^2-2020x+2021})+\sqrt{x^2-2020x+2019})^x, b=(\sqrt{x^2-2020x+2021})-\sqrt{x^2-2020x+2019})^x$

So $a^3+b^3=(a+b)((a+b)^2-6)=2^{1+\frac{3x}{2}}$

i'm stuck:)

Comment: Squaring $u+v$ is not $u^2+v^2.$

Comment: Also, squaring $2^{1+3x/4}$ gives $2^{2+3x/2}.$

Comment: Also you parentheses don’t balance.

Comment: i passed some step

Comment: It looks so complex that the answer must be simple (and it is)

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Set $t = (x^2 - 2020x + 2020),$ express the LHS in terms of $t$, see what the value of $t$ is when $x=1$, and then see what happens to both the LHS and RHS when $x = 1.$

To me, given the query's tags, the real challenge of the problem is to find a **pre-calculus** approach to determining whether any solution other than $x=1$ is possible.

Frankly, this seems to exclude taking derivatives, since that would require a knowledge of Calculus.  The only pre-calculus approach that I can think of is **experimenting** with what happens when $x < 0, ~x=0, ~0 < x < 1,$ and $~x > 1.$

Note that it is presumed that the problem is based on the Real Numbers only, rather than the Complex Numbers.  Therefore, since the LHS terms of $\sqrt{t+1}$ and $\sqrt{t-1}$ are involved, you can **not** allow $(t+1) < 0$ or $(t-1) < 0$.